# Ios Firebase error on authentication

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I have a problem when I'm trying to test my firebase authentication! I want to test the connection to my database but and so I tried to login without having a user registered but my function handle errors it's always giving me the default error

My Authentication class:

```
    import Foundation
import FirebaseAuth

typealias LoginHandler = (_ msg: String?) -> Void;

struct LoginErrorCode {
    static let INVALID_EMAIL = "Invalid Email";
    static let WRONG_PASSWORD = "Wrong Password";
    static let PROBLEM_CONNECTING = "Problem Connecting";
    static let USER_NOT_FOUND = "User not found"
    static let EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE = "Email Already in Use";
    static let WEAK_PASSWORD = "Weak Password";

}

class AuthProvider {
    private static let _instance = AuthProvider();

    static var Instance: AuthProvider {
        return _instance;
    }
    func login(withEmail: String, password: String, loginHandler: LoginHandler?){

        Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: withEmail, password: password, completion:  {(user, error) in

            if error != nil {
                self.handleErrors(err: error as! NSError, loginHandler: loginHandler)
            } else {
                loginHandler?(nil);
            }
        });
    }

    func signUp(withEmail: String, password: String, loginHandler: LoginHandler?){

        Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: withEmail, password: password) { (user, error) in

            if error != nil {
                self.handleErrors(err: error as! NSError, loginHandler: loginHandler);

            } else {
                if user?.user.uid != nil {

                    self.login(withEmail: withEmail, password: password, loginHandler: loginHandler);


                }
            }
        };
    }







private func handleErrors(err: NSError, loginHandler: LoginHandler?){

    if let errCode = AuthErrorCode(rawValue: err.code){

        switch  errCode {

        case .wrongPassword:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.WRONG_PASSWORD);
            break;
        case .invalidEmail:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.INVALID_EMAIL);
            break;
        case .userNotFound:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.USER_NOT_FOUND);
            break;
        case .emailAlreadyInUse:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE);
            break;
        case .weakPassword:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.WEAK_PASSWORD);
            break;
        default:
            loginHandler?(LoginErrorCode.PROBLEM_CONNECTING);
                          break;
        }
    }


}
```

} // class

I changed the login methods in the console to Email/Password to yes, and I currently have a API Key.

Any idea of what the problem should be?

Answer (score 0):

To better diagnose the issue, if you haven't already, you could enable debug logging with

`-FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled`

to get a better error message. In the Xcode scheme editor:

[image: Xcode Project Scheme Editor]

Comment: I have done that to test the error "Wrong Password" but it gave me the default one "Problem Connecting";

Comment: It sounds like this isn't an authentication issue.  I'll update my answer.